# Problems installing PHPWord in PHP 5.5.11

Tags: php, phpword

I have the following problem while installing PHPword from composer. I download version 0.13.0 of phpword and version 2.0 of composer but I get the following error:

```
Problem 1
    - laminas/laminas-zendframework-bridge[1.0.0, ..., 1.0.4] require php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (5.5.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laminas/laminas-escaper[2.6.0, ..., 2.6.1] require php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (5.5.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laminas/laminas-zendframework-bridge[1.1.0, ..., 1.1.1] require php ^5.6 || ^7.0 || ^8.0 -> your php version (5.5.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laminas/laminas-zendframework-bridge[1.2.0, ..., 1.3.0] require php ^7.3 || ^8.0 -> your php version (5.5.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laminas/laminas-zendframework-bridge[1.4.0, ..., 1.4.1] require php ^7.3 || ~8.0.0 || ~8.1.0 -> your php version (5.5.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laminas/laminas-escaper 2.9.0 require php ^7.3 || ~8.0.0 || ~8.1.0 -> your php version (5.5.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laminas/laminas-zendframework-bridge[1.5.0, ..., 1.6.1] require php >=7.4, <8.2 -> your php version (5.5.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laminas/laminas-zendframework-bridge 1.7.0 requires php ~8.0.0 || ~8.1.0 || ~8.2.0 -> your php version (5.5.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laminas/laminas-escaper[2.7.0, ..., 2.8.0] require php ^7.3 || ~8.0.0 -> your php version (5.5.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laminas/laminas-escaper 2.10.0 requires php ^7.4 || ~8.0.0 || ~8.1.0 -> your php version (5.5.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laminas/laminas-escaper[2.11.0, ..., 2.12.0] require php ^7.4 || ~8.0.0 || ~8.1.0 || ~8.2.0 -> your php version (5.5.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpoffice/phpword 0.18.3 requires laminas/laminas-escaper ^2.2 -> satisfiable by laminas/laminas-escaper[2.2.0, ..., 2.12.0].
    - laminas/laminas-escaper[2.2.0, ..., 2.5.2] require laminas/laminas-zendframework-bridge ^1.0 -> satisfiable by laminas/laminas-zendframework-bridge[1.0.0, ..., 1.7.0].
    - Root composer.json requires phpoffice/phpword ^0.18.3 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpword[0.18.3].
```

someone managed to install phpword in this version of php 5.5.11

Install various versions of composer, including version 2.2, which is compatible with versions greater than php 5.3, and download phpword version 0.13.0, I have tried other lower versions, but I cannot install.

Comment: The requirements are there for a reason, and the minimum version of PHP that PHPWord supports is 5.6. And PHP5.5 is extremely outdated. I'd suggest finding a way to upgrade your version of PHP